# Why can't we just replace cancerous organs with artificial organs, before the cancer spreads?

Tags: cancer, stomach, technology, artificial

This is coming from someone who has no idea what he's talking about (me), but I was thinking about the concept of artificial organs.

I thought that, if it were possible to recreate organs artificially (say, a device that acts as a replacement for a stomach), you could swap out an organ that has cancer (say, stomach cancer) and just replace it, before the cancer has chance to spread elsewhere.

It seems easier than trying to find a cure (though, as a developer, I think maybe we should be wary about how devices can be connected to -- thinking about the hacking of pacemakers)

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is done for [early-stage liver cancers](https://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/liver-cancer/treatment/surgery/liver-transplant/who-can-have-transplant). One problem is that lots of the common cancers are in organs that we cannot transplant (like the bowel). In other cases (like the lung), cancer often presents after it has spread to other areas. I’ll try to formalise an answer but need to do some research.

Comment: Also, here on Medical Sciences, it’s good to have some sources or baseline research in your question 

Comment: Prior research isn't just good, it's a requirement. You don't need to answer the question yourself, but you do need to show you've made an effort to find the answer and what you found. I think one place to start would be finding out which organs even have artificial replacements. I think you'll find there aren't many.

Comment: "...if it were possible to recreate organs artificially..." That's a problem. I think it would be literally impossible to build a mechanical stomach, pancreas, intestines, brain, etc. The easiest organs to replace with mechanical devices are those that do one thing or very few things. It's probably easier to grow organs artificially sometime in the future.

Comment: Also, one can live without a stomach; it is not easy, but it can be done. The problem with stomach cancer is that it's hard to detect before it's too advanced to cure.